# How can I use 'yield' statement in python 3.8 's asynchronous programming？

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In python's asyncio asynchronous programming (version 3.7 or below), if I would like to manually let a coroutine gives back its control to the main event loop , I can use this code:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def switch():
    yield
    return

async def task():
    # ...do something
    # ...
    await switch() # then this coroutine will be suspended and other will be triggered
    # ...
    # ... do something else when it's triggered again.
```

However in python3.8 "@coroutine" decorator is deprecated . And besides I could not use yield in a 'async def' (since it will define a async generator but not coroutine) . So how could I achive the same function?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to implement your own ``switch`` coroutine? Practically all events loops consider their respective ``sleep(0)`` to do this. On top, not every event loop will respond properly to an empty ``yield``.

Comment: `@asyncio.coroutine` is deprecated, but `@types.coroutine` isn't (and won't be), so you should use that. If you look carefully, `asyncio.sleep` uses that one internally as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLDR: Do not use an explicit `yield` to switch coroutines. For `asyncio`, use `asyncio.sleep(0)` instead.

---

Practically all event loops consider their respective `sleep` with a duration of 0 to mean "let other coroutines run".
For `asyncio`, use `asyncio.sleep(0)` to let other coroutines run.

```
async def task():
    # ...do something
    # ...
    await asyncio.sleep(0) # then this coroutine will be suspended and other will be triggered
    # ...
    # ... do something else when it's triggered again.
```

> #### [Sleeping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping) (`asyncio`)

> `sleep()` always suspends the current task, allowing other tasks to run.

> #### [Checkpoints](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#checkpoints) (`trio`)

> … it’s useful to know that `await trio.sleep(0)` is an idiomatic way to execute a checkpoint without doing anything else …

> #### [Time](https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#time) (`curio`)

> Sleep for a specified number of seconds. If the number of seconds is 0, execution switches to the next ready task (if any).

---

If for some reason an explicit `yield` to the event loop is needed, create a custom class and `yield` in its `__await__` special method.

```
class Switch:
    """Switch coroutines by yielding to the event loop"""
    def __await__(self):
        yield
```

Note that this sends a bare `None` to the event loop. Whether and how an event loop handles this signal depends on the async library used.

Comment: Thanks bro ,using __await__method could achieve the same function.The reason why I'm disliking await asyncio.sleep(0) is that it's 10% slower than self define switcher......

Comment: I've looked into py3.8's source code implementation of asyncio.sleep(), it uses @types.coroutine decorator. Using this instead of asyncio.sleep(0) could speedup about 12% on my pc.