# Why are my async functions not running in parallel?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm trying to understand asyncio in Python. I'm expecting my two async functions to run at the same time with the output similar to below.

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

Instead, I'm getting a list of 'foo'.

```
async def print_foo():
    while True:
        print("foo")

async def print_bar():
    while True:
        print("bar")

async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        task1 = tg.create_task(print_foo())
        task2 = tg.create_task(print_bar())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Could someone explain why I see this behaviour and how I can get the two async functions to run at the same time?

Comment: In short, another task can only run while one task `await`s something.

Comment: The `print_foo()` function is not awaiting anything itself. Therefore it will never yield control back to `asyncio` to choose something else to run.

Answer (score 4):

The `while` loops in `print_foo` and `print_bar` are blocking the event loop from handling other async tasks that have been submitted to run. One way to work around this is to use `asyncio.sleep` to yield back to the event loop:

```
import asyncio
async def print_foo():
   while True:
      print('foo')
      await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def print_bar():
   while True:
      print('bar')
      await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def main():
   async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
      task1 = tg.create_task(print_foo())
      task2 = tg.create_task(print_bar())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: Interesting,, `sleep(0)` strikes me as a little... odd. Is there nothing like `await asyncio.yield()`? I searched through the docs but couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: @Alexander Sleeping is the standard, default approach, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60603096/how-can-i-use-yield-statement-in-python-3-8-s-asynchronous-programming and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586879/does-await-in-python-yield-to-the-event-loop

Comment: I still find it odd, but the context is useful. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: While this does cause the tasks in the question to perform context switches, it's almost never actually the right thing to do in a real program. If a long-running task doesn't have any "natural" context-switch points, it should usually be run in an executor, not on the event loop.